# How to get redshift DDL programmatically?

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift, ddl

Iam using pg_dump command for dumping the ddl. but it's not giving me the distkey and  sortkey is there other way to get a full length ddl with create statment (with distkey & sortkey), alter statment, comment on columns and table and grant statement. Please help me ouy

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  AWSLAbs on github (https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils) has many utilities for managing Redshift.  One of which is a view that can be used to gather the full DDL of Redshift tables - v_generate_tbl_ddl.  See: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_tbl_ddl.sql

Comment: How much time will it take to create view coz I see it's taking so much time can you tell me

Comment: View created but after fetching table It's giving me error too long for type character varying (798)

Comment: I'm not associated with AWSLabs and had no involvement with their work.  So I cannot speak on their behalf.  That said I've used their work many times with success.  As you can see this SQL pulls information from many system tables to ensure that any table DDL created is complete.  If you have a large number of tables this can take a while to generate and the result can be a lot of text.  There are a number of reasons that it take a long time (locks, connection BW, system load etc.) but if you are only interested in a single table you can add a WHERE clause.

Comment: VARCHAR(798) is a very specific size and I don't see it defined in the view.  So I expect this error is being produced by due to some implicit casting.  You can attempt to isolate the issue (which table, which attribute in the view is being inspected etc.) and find a work-around.  There seems to be an open ticket for this issue on github https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/issues/548 but if you provide more info here on what is causing the error I'll take a look and provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I had to dump ddl from about 1300 tables to separate files.  I wrote a lambda in python to do it.  It uploads all the files to a s3 bucket but you can modify the code to put the files on you local drive.  Here is the code:

```
import pg8000 as rs
```

import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

```
rs_user_name= 'awsuser'
rs_password = 'your-password'
rs_database_name= 'your-database' 
rs_host= 'your-redshift-cluster'
bucket_name = 'your-s3-bucket'

rs_conn = rs.connect(
    host=rs_host, 
    user=rs_user_name,
    password=rs_password , 
    port=5439, 
    database=rs_database_name,
    timeout=10
    )
    
with rs_conn.cursor() as rs_cursor:
    schema_qry = f"select table_schema,table_name from information_schema.tables where table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and table_schema not in ('pg_catalog','information_schema','pg_internal')"
    print(schema_qry)
    rs_cursor.execute(schema_qry)
    
    for r in rs_cursor:
        print(f"{r[0]}.{r[1]}")
        ddl_qry = f"show table {r[0]}.{r[1]}"
        s3_path =f'{r[0]}_{r[1]}.sql'
        print(ddl_qry)
        print(s3_path)
        with rs_conn.cursor() as rs_cursor_ddl:
            rs_cursor_ddl.execute(ddl_qry)
            for r_ddl in rs_cursor_ddl:
                print(bucket_name)
                    
                print(r_ddl[0])
                ddl_string = r_ddl[0]
                encoded_string = ddl_string.encode("utf-8")
                s3 = boto3.resource('s3') 
                s3.Bucket(bucket_name).put_object(Key=s3_path, Body=encoded_string)
```